# Reproducing plot in R using ggplot (Area plot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graphics, data-visualization

I'm trying to reproduce a plot in R where I have the data but not the code.
I think using ggplot will be the best solution.

The plot should look like this:

[image: Click]

My data:

A dataframe (d) where column 1 ("Year") gives the year (1960 - 2000) and 15 other columns ("Group 1", "Group 2"...) giving the value of the group. Thus, each row contains the year and the values for the certain group.
(e.g. (1) 1960; 455; 367; 477; 788; 456; 334; 456;...)

I already tried some experiments with geom_area, but this does not result in the intendet graph.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = Year, y = d[,2]))+
  geom_area(fill = "#00AFBB", color = "blue")
```

Here I get n (n = # of Years) very thin bars representing the value of group 1 against a certain year.

Hope you can help me out maybe with some ideas or a tutorial. Is area plot the right choice for what I want to do?

Best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the data from `wide` to `long` format and then it should work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
d <- gather(d, Group, value, Group1:Group15)
ggplot(d, aes(x = Year, y = value, fill = Group))+
  geom_area()
```